# How to flash a Zephyr RTOS sample project to the nrf52840 dongle using J-Link Base debugger and SWD

Tags: microcontroller, swd, rtos, j-link, nordic

I'm a beginner at this, I'm a software developer so I've never worked with hardware but now I need to and I don't seem to be able to make it work.

I would need help as to how can I flash a Zephyr RTOS sample project to the nrf52840 dongle using J-Link Base debugger and SWD, for beginners.

I've done everything software wise, all I need is for the J-Link to flash the dongle with the Zephyr sample program I want, but it doesn't work.

Here's what I have so far:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Zephyr RTOS
- J-Link software installed and physical debugger -> Adafruit JTAG (2x10 2.54mm) to SWD (2x5 1.27mm) Cable Adapter Board -> TagConnect TC2050-IDC-NL-050-ALL cable -> nrf52840 dongle

I've had this error trying to flash a sample project to the dongle:

```
-- west flash: rebuilding
ninja: no work to do.
-- west flash: using runner jlink
-- runners.jlink: Flashing file: /home/anon/zephyrproject/zephyr/samples/bluetooth/hci_usb/build/zephyr/zephyr.hex
SEGGER J-Link Commander V7.20 (Compiled Apr 28 2021 17:38:41)
DLL version V7.20, compiled Apr 28 2021 17:38:26


J-Link Command File read successfully.
Processing script file...

J-Link connection not established yet but required for command.
Connecting to J-Link via USB...O.K.
Firmware: J-Link V11 compiled Apr 27 2021 16:36:21
Hardware version: V11.00
S/N: 51015130
License(s): GDB
VTref=0.000V
Target connection not established yet but required for command.
Device "NRF52" selected.


Connecting to target via SWD
Cannot connect to target.

Target connection not established yet but required for command.
Device "NRF52" selected.


Connecting to target via SWD
Cannot connect to target.

Target connection not established yet but required for command.
Device "NRF52" selected.


Connecting to target via SWD
Cannot connect to target.

Writing failed.

Reading failed.


Script processing completed.
```

I've read somewhere that a problem could be VTref=0.000V so I figured the dongle needs some electricity so I connected it to a usb hub, turns the green light on the J-Link off, connected it to a pc, same, the same pc that was trying to flash it, same, to a plug on the wall, same.

When the dongle is connected to a usb hub the light turns red but the J-Link is off, when I disconnect it, the J-Link turns back to green and the dongle is off.

I have absolutely no idea what to do, I've been at it for months ( I didn't even know about J-Link until recently ) and I've read that the dongle could be faulty so I bought multiple and they all have the same problem.

If I were to have to power the dongle while it is connected to the J-Link, how can I do it without the J-Link disconnecting ?

That's what it looks like for now:
[image]
[image]

Thank you so much for your help.

**EDIT:**

Ok I think I've figured the problem out, It seems to be the Adafruit JTAG to SWD Cable Adapter Board that doesn't work somehow. when I disconnect it it suddenly works so it is the faulty thing for now.

Can you guys help me find a replacement for it ? I would need an adapter from J-Link's 20 pins to either the three of the last picture, they have a lot of adapters on the website but I don't want to make a mistake again, can you tell me which one I should buy ?:

https://www.tag-connect.com/product-category/products/adapters

cables on the pic from left to right:
TC2050-IDC: https://www.tag-connect.com/product/tc2050-idc-tag-connect-2050-idc
TC2050-IDC-050-20-ALL: https://www.tag-connect.com/product/tc2050-idc-050-all-20
TC2050-IDC-050-ALL: https://www.tag-connect.com/product/tc2050-idc-050-all

[image]

Comment: Hey Sacha, My sympathy with you, another Sof(t)i.. :-) I do not have access to J-link right the moment, had before. Please post the link to the J-link and NRF52840 datasheet. For sure you will get an answer. Meantime, unless J-link supplies Vcc (forgot), you need to power NRF52, by plugging it to USB host/hub. The LED lights are likely "controlled", means your J-link potentially is ok. One stupid thought: check if the j-tag connector has the "key" pin, otherwise, if two sides are mating correct, not rotated. You can hit me up here by "@jay".

Comment: Thanks for helping Jay, I've added the datasheets at the end of the post and I've tried to plug it to a usb hub like you've said and I've updated the post with it

Comment: Jlinks don't power the device being flashed (unless you take special steps). Connect the JLINK then plug the dongle in to your power brick. After taht, try flashing.

Comment: @pgvoorhees I tried that, when I do the jlink light stays green and the dongle doesn't light up, I tried flashing anyway and it gives me the same error and VTref=0.000V

Comment: Ok I think I've figured the problem out, I've edited the post, can you let me know what you think ?

Comment: I’d suggest you ‘beep’ out the connections with a multimeter. Only 4 should be needed - 0V, swd,swclk and vtref to 3.3V. Work that back through the dongle schematic and the pinout of the jlink.  My suggestion  would be to get a nrf52 DK and avoid the hassle.